# Multiset operators on nested tables with non scalar types

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sql-developer

I have a function, which performs multiset operation on two nested tables and returns result:

```
function odejmijEgz(tab typ_NT) return typ_NT is
  tab1 typ_NT := typ_NT();
  cursor c_osr_egz is select distinct o.id_osrodek oid, o.nazwa_o nazwa_o from egzaminy e
    right join osrodki o on e.id_osrodek = o.id_osrodek
    where e.id_osrodek is null;
  i number;
  begin
    for v_osr in c_osr_egz loop
      i := c_osr_egz%rowcount;
      tab1.extend;
      tab1(i) := v_osr;
    end loop;
  return tab multiset except tab1;
  end odejmijEgz;
```

where types are declared in pl/sql block:

```
type typ_Rec is record(Id osrodki.id_osrodek%type,
                        Nazwa osrodki.nazwa_o%type);                 
type typ_NT is table of typ_Rec;
```

Parameter of the function is nested table, populated with records.

When I use `multiset except` in function I got an error:

```
Error: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MULTISET_EXCEPT_ALL'
```

But if I change it to `multiset union` it works. The tables are of the same type. Whats wrong with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MULTISET EXCEPT](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/operators006.htm#SQLRF51166)

> The element types of the nested tables **must be comparable**.

[Comparison Conditions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions002.htm#SQLRF52105)

> Two objects of nonscalar type are comparable if they are of the same
>   named type and there is a one-to-one correspondence between their
>   elements. **In addition, nested tables of user-defined object types,
>   even if their elements are comparable, must have MAP methods defined
>   on them to be used in equality or IN conditions.**

The problem is, the above can not be done with a `record` type. `record` types have only fields, and can not have member functions. Furthermore:

[Record Comparisons](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS496)

> Records cannot be tested natively for nullity, equality, or
>   inequality.
>
> These BOOLEAN expressions are illegal:
>
> - My_Record IS NULL
> - My_Record_1 = My_Record_2
> - My_Record_1 > My_Record_2

This fails:

```
create or replace package p1 as
  type typ_Rec is record(id customers.customer_id%type, name customers.cust_first_name%type);                 
  type typ_NT is table of typ_Rec;
  function f1 (tab typ_NT) return typ_NT;
end;
/

Package created.

create or replace package body p1 as
  function f1 (tab typ_NT) return typ_NT as
    tab1 typ_NT := typ_NT();
  begin
    return tab multiset except tab1;
  end;
end;
/

Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors.

SQL> show errors
Errors for PACKAGE BODY P1:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
5/5      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
5/12     PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
         'MULTISET_EXCEPT_ALL'
```

`UNION` works, because you did not specify `ALL` or `DISTINCT`, and in this case, `UNION ALL` is the default. `UNION ALL` does not need to perform comparison. But if you try `UNION DISTINCT` (which removes duplicates), that will also fail:

```
create or replace package body p1 as
  function f1 (tab typ_NT) return typ_NT as
    tab1 typ_NT := typ_NT();
  begin
    return tab multiset union distinct tab1;
  end;
end;
/

Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors.

SQL> show errors
Errors for PACKAGE BODY P1:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
5/5      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
5/12     PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
         'MULTISET_UNION_DISTINCT'
```

You need an `object` type for this.

```
create or replace type typ_Obj as object
(
  id number(6),
  name varchar2(20)
);
/

Type created.

create or replace package p1 as
  type typ_NT is table of typ_Obj;
  function f1 (tab typ_NT) return typ_NT;
end;
/

Package created.

create or replace package body p1 as
  function f1 (tab typ_NT) return typ_NT as
    tab1 typ_NT := typ_NT();
  begin
    return tab multiset except tab1;
  end;
end;
/

Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors.

SQL> show errors
Errors for PACKAGE BODY P1:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
5/5      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
5/12     PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
         'MULTISET_EXCEPT_ALL'
```

Notice how it still failed, because I did not define the `MAP` function, I did not tell the database how it can compare two user-defined objects. Now try again, this time with defining `MAP` (and here I assume objects have unique identifiers and two objects equal if their identifiers equal):

```
create or replace type typ_Obj as object
(
  id number(6),
  name varchar2(20),
  MAP MEMBER FUNCTION get_idno RETURN NUMBER
);
/

Type created.

CREATE or replace TYPE BODY typ_Obj AS
  MAP MEMBER FUNCTION get_idno RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN id;
  END;
END;
/

Type body created.

create or replace package body p1 as
  function f1 (tab typ_NT) return typ_NT as
    tab1 typ_NT := typ_NT();
  begin
    return tab multiset except tab1;
  end;
end;
/

Package body created.
```

And finally it worked, no warning.

Comment: Ah, it's `MULTISET UNION`. Right! (checked the docs after I noticed the multiset)

Comment: @TypoCubeᵀᴹ For regular `UNION`, the default is the `UNION DISTINCT` behaviour, but that is not a valid syntax, it is just simply `UNION` or `UNION ALL`. But this is `MULTISET UNION`, where the default is `MULTISET UNION ALL`. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/operators006.htm#SQLRF51170 - The ALL keyword instructs Oracle to return all elements that are in the two input nested tables, including duplicate values and duplicate NULL occurrences. This is the default.